# Tweet a message using python

Tags: python, twitter

i am a newbie in Python and want to try to tweet using python using this code, but after i run it, in python shell said that

```
from twython import Twython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twython'
```

Can someone help what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you install the package? Your provided code is irrelevant to your issue since it fails on the import line itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Python family! When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object, initializing it. If the named module cannot be found, a `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised.

As a beginner, you should learn how to install a package in Python by going through the tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/

Next, you should follow the installation guide in 
https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/install.html

In the command prompt, you should run

```
pip install twython
```

Observe if any error pops up during the installation.

To see if Twython works correctly, start Python in the command prompt,

```
python
```

In the Python environment, run the following command:

```
>>> from twython import Twython
```

If Twython is installed correctly, you should not see the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should try again pip install command, 
Also:

1. If you are using an different place such as Pycharm or Jupyter or Anaconda, you must reinstall that module in that working environments

   2. If you are using python's own ide, try add your current python path to system path
   3. Re-read usage of your module

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError means that the module is not installed. Sometimes may be the module is installed but it is installed in a place where python does not look for it. In your case I feel you have not installed twython.

Open command prompt and type the following command
**pip install twython**

This should install the twython and after this if you run your file the error will not appear.

Check this out for more information on twython https://pypi.org/project/twython/